# Best approach to implement Ajax file upload?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, file-upload

How can I implement an "ajax" file upload (does this exist with this name, or this is just an iframe which will handle the file upload?) for a certain form image? Lets suppose a picture for a user profile, this means the user can upload the picture, but until he presses "Save", nothing will be persisted.
Other question is: how can I see the user picture after the upload ends, but before the profile form is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to implement ajax upload your self read about [XMLHttpRequest 2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) and formData(click the link to see if your desired browsers will support it).

But if you want to make it work in browsers that don't support ajax file upload, you will need to implement some kind of abstraction that will degrade and provide you with alternative iFrame version([read here](http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/)).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Zurb's Ajax Upload](http://zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload). It's quite old now, you might want to check if it's still working with the actual version of jQuery.